# jQuery mobile mega dropdown adds more and more buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jquery plugin to generate a mega dropdown on my mobile website:

[image]

The menu is generated dynamically: everytime the user clicks on the right arrow, an api call is made to gather all sub-points to the clicked menu-entry. Down the menu everything works fine, but when I click on "back" it seems that there is added a forward/back-button for each menu-level:

[image]

This is my code:

```
// Catching the click-event
$(document).on('click','.next-button', function(){
    var subCatContainer = $(this).next('.subcats');
    var current = $(this).parent('.shopCatWithSub');
    var categoryid = current.data('categoryuuid');

    console.log('Next clicked');
    console.log(categoryid);

    if(typeof categoryid !== "undefined"){
        buildSubcats(categoryid, subCatContainer, standardUrl);
    } else {
        console.log("No category set!");
    }
});

// Get subcategories from API:
function buildSubcats(catid, subCatContainer, standardUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://my-awesome-url.de/api?category-id=' + catid,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            handleResponse(data, subCatContainer, standardUrl);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrow) {
            console.log(errorThrow);
            if (jQuery.isFunction(callback)) {
            }       
        }
    });
}

// Build and add new nav-elements:
function handleResponse(data, subCatContainer, standardUrl){
    var output = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, category){
        var element = '';
        var uladd = "";
        var aClassAdd = "";
        if(category.hasSubcategories) {
            uladd = '<ul class="subcats"></ul>';
            aClassAdd = 'has-next-button';
        }
        element = '<li class="shopCatWithSub" data-categoryuuid="' + category.categoryUUID + '">'
            + '<a class="text-truncate menu-item ' + aClassAdd + '" href="' + standardUrl + category.categoryUUID + '">'
                + '<i class="icon-' + category.categoryIconClass + ' mr-2"></i>'
                + category.displayName
            + '</a>'
            + uladd 
        + '</li>';

        output += element;
    });
    subCatContainer.empty();
    subCatContainer.html(output);

    // Re-initialize menu
    $('.nav-mobile').mobileMegaMenu();
}
```

I assume that there is a problem with the re-initializing of the complete menu-structure. But I can't figure out how to handle it.

Comment: so your `data` which is returned by the `Ajax` is not the same length every time?

Comment: No, it varies. It depends on the sub-menu. Some have on sub-element, others have 5..

Comment: Off topic: Your call to `empty()` is not needed. The `html()` method already does that. Also, if you did need both you could chain: `blah.empty().html()`